# For/While loop usage

Tags: c, loops

I'm quite new to programming. I've learnt about loop for a while(about 1 month haha). I've done a number of excercises and so far, I've used mainly for loop. I THINK that they are the same, because in the end, you can achieve the same result with any loop. Can anyone enlight me about this? When should we use a for loop and when should we use a while loop. Which one is more likely to stuck in an infinite loop? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops and `while` loops generate *almost* the exact same code underneath.

The idea behind using a `for` is when you need an index or iterator of some sort. A `while` is generally used to check a simple boolean condition.

More specifically, if you're trying to loop over a collection (array, list, etc.) use a `for`. If you're checking to see when the state of something changes, use a `while`.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic type of loop is the `while` loop; use it when you don't know until runtime how many iterations it's going to loop for. A `for` is really just a `while` loop with "convenience" features built in. Use a `for` when the number of iterations is a predictable constant or variable.

Typically, it's more likely that you'll get yourself stuck forever in a `while` loop, due to loop conditions that you think will terminate but actually don't. But I'd choose the type of loop based on the criteria I specified above.

Answer (score 0):

`for(;expression;){/*code*/}` and `while(expression){/*code*/}` are both just goto in this diguise:

```
if (expression is false) goto END;
BEGIN:
  //code here
if (expression is true) goto BEGIN;
END:
```

`do{/*code here*/}while(expression);` is more like this:

```
BEGIN:
  //code here
if (expression is true) goto BEGIN;
```

In assembly these would all consist of jumps and labels.  The one major difference is how a for loop helps with the conciseness and readability of code by grouping all of the significant controlling characteristics of the loop together, specifically the init, condition and increment are all together such that a while loop like this:

```
i=0;
j=size;
while(i < j){
  //possibly lots of code in between
  i++;
  j--;
}
```

would become

```
for(i=0,j=size; i<j; i++,j--){
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your loop needs a changing state variable to express the condition use a `for`-loop. The syntax allows to declare a variable that is local to the loop and to manipulate it explicitly after each iteration.

```
for (unsigned i = k; i < 100; ++i) {
  ...
}
```

is much clearer than its equivalent

```
{
 unsigned i = k;
 if (i < 100) do {
   ...
   if (i < 100) ++i;
   else break;
 } while(1);
}
```